# Ejecutar una funcion cada cierto tiempo con vue

Tags: javascript, vue3

tengo un problema, quiero ejecutar una funcion cada 5 minutos.

Pero me da el siguiente error:  Unexpected identifier 'Promise'
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'Promise' y no ecnuentro como solucionarlo.

Estoy usando vue3

Ya intente haciendo esto:

```
 async mounted(){
    this.seguirEjecutando = setInterval(this.getDataNotifications(),300000)
  },
  beforeUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.seguirEjecutando)
  },
```

Comment: Quita los paréntesis: `setInterval(this.getDataNotifications, 300000)`

Answer (score 1):

Intenta hacerlo así, por que el problemas es que le pasas la función inmediatamente si tener la función de flecha:

```
async mounted(){
    this.seguirEjecutando = setInterval(() => this.getDataNotifications(), 300000)
},
beforeUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.seguirEjecutando)
}
```